# Python pandas tensor access is extremely slow

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a huge tensor with millions of *word triples* and their counts. For example, a *word triple* is a `(word0, link, word1)`. These word triples are collected in a single dictionary where values are their respective counts, e.g. `(word0, link, word1): 15`. Imagine I have millions of such *triples*. After I calculate the occurences I attempt to do other calculations and this is where my python script gets stuck. Here is a part of the code which takes eternity:

```
big_tuple = covert_to_tuple(big_dict)
pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(big_tuple)
pdf.columns = ['word0', 'link', 'word1', 'counts']
total_cnts = pdf.counts.sum()

for _, row in pdf.iterrows():
    w0, link, w1 = row['word0'], row['link'], row['word1']
    w0w1_link = row.counts

    # very slow
    w0_link = pdf[(pdf.word0 == w0) & (pdf.link == link)]['counts'].sum()
    w1_link = pdf[(pdf.word1 == w1) & (pdf.link == link)]['counts'].sum()

    p_w0w1_link = w0w1_link / total_cnts
    p_w0_link = w0_link / total_cnts
    p_w1_link = w1_link / total_cnts
    new_score = log(p_w0w1_link / (p_w0_link * p_w1_link))
    big_dict[(w0, link, w1)] = new_score
```

I profiled my script and it appears that both lines below

```
w0_link = pdf[(pdf.word0 == w0) & (pdf.link == link)]['counts'].sum()  
w1_link = pdf[(pdf.word1 == w1) & (pdf.link == link)]['counts'].sum()
```

take **49%** and **49%** percent of calculation time each. These lines attempt to find the counts for `(word0, link)` and `(word1, link)`.  So, looks like **pdf** accessed like this takes a lot of time? Can I do something to optimize it?

Comment: Please, check my updated answer - I want to understand why the expression for new_score isn't correct.

Comment: ah, yeah, you're right. math... :)

Comment: Exactly :) Eliminating calculation overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, check my solution - I optimized something in calculations (hope without mistakes :))

```
# sample of data
df = pd.DataFrame({'word0': list('aabb'), 'link': list('llll'), 'word1': list('cdcd'),'counts': [10, 20, 30, 40]})

# caching total count
total_cnt = df['counts'].sum()

# two series with sums for all combinations of ('word0', 'link') and ('word1', 'link')
grouped_w0_l = df.groupby(['word0', 'link'])['counts'].sum()/total_cnt
grouped_w1_l = df.groupby(['word1', 'link'])['counts'].sum()/total_cnt

# join sums for grouped ('word0', 'link') to original df
merged_w0 = df.set_index(['word0', 'link']).join(grouped_w0_l, how='left', rsuffix='_w0').reset_index()

# join sums for grouped ('word1', 'link') to merged df
merged_w0_w1 = merged_w0.set_index(['word1', 'link']).join(grouped_w1_l, how='left', rsuffix='_w1').reset_index()

# merged_w0_w1 has enough data for calculation new_score
# check here - I transform the expression
merged_w0_w1['new_score'] = np.log(merged_w0_w1['counts'] * total_cnt / (merged_w0_w1['counts_w0'] * merged_w0_w1['counts_w1']))

# export results to dict (don't know is it really needed or not - you can continue manipulate data with dataframes)
big_dict = merged_w0_w1.set_index(['word0', 'link', 'word1'])['new_score'].to_dict()
```

The expression for new_score is

```
new_score = log(p_w0w1_link / (p_w0_link * p_w1_link))
        = log(w0w1_link / total_cnts / (w0_link / total_cnts * w0_link / total_cnts))
        = log(w0w1_link / total_cnts * (total_cnts * total_cnts / w0_link * w0_link))
        = log(w0w1_link * total_cnts / (w0_link * w0_link))
```

Comment: ok, I went through your example, joining tables is indeed much faster. I think your math calculations are different, here `merged_w0_w1['counts'] * total_cnt`, this should be division, not multiplication since we are computing the probability of a "triple". The rest is just perfect!